# Paypal Payment Standard shopping cart shipping options

Tags: paypal

I am reading the Payments Standard documentation which clearly shows the Paypal shopping cart offering as pull down menu of shipping options after the buyer has logged in or provided billing information.

I have set up several shipping options in my profile for the United States, and set them to "Active", but when I do a checkout from a US addressed account, the shipping charges are always set to the first option in the list in my profile.  No selection pull-down is displayed on the checkout page.

My add-to-cart buttons are not passing shipping options, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.   Apparently, when you create shipping options that apply to specific states, then create other options that apply to 'All states', Paypal ignores that 'All states' options and only presents those that specifically list the state from which the purchase is being made.  In my case there was one such option and it was the only one Paypal would use at checkout.   Manually adding all 50 states individually to my 'all states' shipping options fixed the problem but seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The shipping options will default to the cheapest option by default.  So if the first option is the cheapest, this will be what it defaults to.  You will not see the options for the drop down to select a different shipping option until after you sign into your PayPal account, or enter in your credit card information and continue to the second payment page.  Once on this page this is where your buyers will have an option to choose a different shipping option.

Comment: That was my understanding from the documentation, but that is not what is happening. The shipping is calculated on the first option in the list, which is not the cheapest, and no other options are presented after logging in to the Paypal account.

Comment: It should be getting calculated based on the cheapiest option.  Unless you are using Express Checkout or the cart upload where you are setting a default.  Can you provide a link to your checkout so that I can walk thru and see what its doing, and check a few things on my end.